# Is it necessary to nest a double COUNT here?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have three tables for a service that sells tickets for events:

```
Event(id)
Ticket(id, venue_id, seller_id)
Venue(id, event_id)
Seller(id)
```

And I would like to detect, for every event that I have, how many sellers (of type 1) there are that have only only ticket for sale (and for that ticket to be of the corresponding event). Like

```
Event_id; First_time_sellers
2814;3
3092;24
124;1
...
```

I have attempted this with two queries, both failing getting wrong results

```
SELECT event_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT rookie_seller)
FROM
(SELECT event_id,
    rookie_seller,
    tickets
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT event.id AS event_id,
    seller.id AS rookie_seller,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ticket.id) AS tickets
FROM ticket
JOIN venue ON ticket.venue_id = venue.id
JOIN event ON venue.event_id = event.id
JOIN seller ON ticket.seller_id = seller.id
WHERE seller.type = 1
AND ticket.isforsale = 1
GROUP BY rookie_seller) a
WHERE tickets = 1) b
GROUP BY event_id
```

and

```
SELECT event.id,
    a.seller_id,
    a.tickets
FROM ticket
JOIN (
    SELECT seller.id AS seller_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ticket.id) AS tickets
FROM ticket
JOIN seller ON ticket.seller_id = seller.id
WHERE seller.type = 1
AND ticket.isforsale = 1
GROUP BY seller_id) a ON ticket.seller_id = a.seller_id
JOIN venue ON ticket.venue_id = venue.id
JOIN event ON venue.event_id = event.id
WHERE a.tickets = 1
```

I am really not sure what the problem is. the joins should be fine, and the conditions on the count as well, right?

Thanks for any piece of advice :)

Comment: Kindly provide your sample data, the result you are getting and expected data

Answer (score 0):

You do need a subquery for this.  But you can do it more simply:

```
SELECT event_id, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT s.id, v.event_id, COUNT(*) as numTickets
      FROM ticket t JOIN
           seller s
           ON t.seller_id = s.id JOIN
           venue v
           ON t.venue_id = v.id
      WHERE s.type = 1 AND t.isforsale = 1
      GROUP BY s.id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
     ) s
GROUP BY event_id;
```